# Move screen to certain position

Tags: android

When I get a result from an activity in `OnActivityResult()` I need the `ScrollView` to be positioned at a certain position.  How can I move the view to be positioned to where I need it to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the view in the scroll view that needs to be focused [requestChildFocus](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#requestChildFocus%28android.view.View,%20android.view.View%29) or [requestChildRectangleOnScreen()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#requestChildRectangleOnScreen%28android.view.View,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20boolean%29). If you know the exact x,y coordinates you need to scroll to, use the [scrollTo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#scrollTo%28int,%20int%29) method.

Comment: What caught me out: requestChildFocus's first argument is its direct child.  So in my case it was the owning layout of the child that I actually wanted to give focus.